# What is a "family group" as it pertains to quarantine orders?

Tags: new-york-state, legal-terms, covid-19, travel

New York currently has travel restrictions in place, which require individuals coming in from specific states to quarantine for 2 weeks. They use the definition of "quarantine" as defined by the New York Department of Health. When talking about where individuals can stay during quarantine, [it says](https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2020/03/quarantine_guidance_0.pdf):

> Separate quarters with separate bathroom facilities for each individual or family group. Access to a sink with soap and water, and paper towels is needed.

How is "family" defined in this situation? For example, if someone travels to New York to visit and stay with their parents, are they considered quarantined while staying at their parents' house? What if they are visiting their aunt, or brother, etc?

Basically, if each "family group" has their own quarters, does that mean you can only be sharing quarters with your immediate family (spouse and kids; people you normally live with full-time)? Or can you share quarters with anyone who is part of your actual family?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no definition, and no legal basis for assuming a particular interpretation. Therefore, the term has its "ordinary meaning". A family group is what an ordinary reasonable person would consider to be a family group. The governor could publish an order defining "family group" for the purpose of this order. Otherwise, the judge or jury would look at the facts surrounding the case and determine if Billy cannot reasonably be considered a part of the family group.

Comment: Does this mean that under the law; a person could be charged with violating quarantine in these circumstances, and then it would be up to a legal case to decide if the charges were legitimate?

Comment: It is always up to a legal process to decide if the charges are legitimate. The court would have to decide whether the particular act was a "violation". This also includes the interpretation of "from a state", given the land boundaries of New York. The adjacent states qualify, as does Florida under one version of "positive test" (the meaning of positive test rate must also be decided).